# How to add links of other HTML files to index.html automatically using gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Something like archive pages on WordPress blogs. I'm using this [gulp script](https://github.com/darylldoyle/Gulp-Email-Creator/blob/master/gulpfile.js)  it can generate multiple pages but can show only once when it runs the server and open the page in the browser.

```
  server: {
            baseDir: "./output",
            index: "test-template.html"
        },
```

I want test-template.html should have links of

templateA.html
templateB.html
templateC.html

so in the browser instead remembering and typing URL of these files I can just open by clicking on the link on index.html page

Is there any plugin to do this?

Comment: You want a gulp task that would generate links to all the html files in your given directory and put it in test-template.html?

Answer (score 7):

There are two packages that may be helpfull. Please double check task configs, to target your paths.

## gulp-inject

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject

Workflow looks pretty same as above.

#### Somewere in test-template.html

```
<!-- inject:html -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

#### gulpfile.js

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.src('test-template.html')
  .pipe(inject(
    gulp.src(['templates/*.html'], { read: false }), {
      transform: function (filepath) {
        if (filepath.slice(-5) === '.html') {
          return '<li><a href="' + filepath + '">' + filepath + '</a></li>';
        }
        // Use the default transform as fallback: 
        return inject.transform.apply(inject.transform, arguments);
      }
    }
  ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

## gulp-linker [depracated]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-linker

Create gulp task and inside test-template.html insert defined html comments (between this comments the tmpl will be inserted).

#### Somewere in test-template.html

```
<!--LINKS-->
<!--LINKS END-->
```

#### gulpfile.js

```
var linker = require('gulp-linker'),

// Read templates 
gulp.src('test-template.html')
  // Link the JavaScript 
  .pipe(linker({
    scripts: [ "templates/*.html" ],
    startTag: '<!--LINKS-->',
    endTag: '<!--LINKS END-->',
    fileTmpl: '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
    appRoot: 'www/'
  }))
  // Write modified files to www/ 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/'));
```